# Adding a string before a nested list using Python

Tags: python, nested-lists

I have a nested list, for example:

```
names = [['James', 'Logan', 'Timothy'], ['Ander', 'John', 'Henry']]
```

and before each name, I would like to add this string `'His name is: '` before each name.
So it should print, line by line:

```
His name is: James
His name is: Logan
His name is: Timothy
His name is: Ander
His name is: John
His name is: Henry
```

I used

```
for n in names: print(f'His name is: {n}')
```

but that didn't give me the output I was looking for.
Can you please help me figure out how to do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read  [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) - especially the "Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first." part

Comment: You'll probably want to look at [Flatten a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2158395/5763413), the use of [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/), and [`for` loops](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop).

Comment: The problem statement is not clear to me. Do you want to actually mutate the list or do you want to prepend that string only during printing/display?

Comment: I used this at first, but didn't give me what I was looking for: ' for n in names: print(f'His name is: {n}') '

Comment: One list, one loop, as in your original question an hour ago…  Now you have two nested lists and would need two nested loops…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a nested list. So, use nested for loop -

```
names = [['James', 'Logan', 'Timothy'], ['Ander', 'John', 'Henry']]

for i in names:
    for n in i:
        print(f'His name is: {n}')
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
from itertools import chain


for name in chain.from_iterable(names):
    print(f'His name is: {name}')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid using a nested loop or `itertools` you can just combine all the nested lists using `sum`:

```
names = [['James', 'Logan', 'Timothy'], ['Ander', 'John', 'Henry']]

for name in sum(names, []):
    print(f'His name is: {name}')
```